# Creating/digitizing roads using ArcMap editor?

Tags: arcmap, line, editing, digitizing

This is probably very basic but I am not able to figure out. I am trying to digitize roads by drawing lines. I go to Editor>Star Editing, select the layer, select my layer under 'create features'. Then under 'construction tools', polygon is selected by default but there is no lines or road option. When I try to create a road, it creates a polygon.

How do I create a road/line?

[image: ArcMap]

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have a definition query on your line layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layer type is Polygon, that's why it is not showing any line, while creating shapefile/feature class you have specified the polygon type.

Try creating a new shapefile/Feature Class and then specify Line Featues in the Type. This will resolve your issue.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted.